# Data Feed to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to collect inputs for several users and feed the data into a MySQL database. Are there any more efficient options other than a web form or HTML form which directly feeds the data to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you need some kind of user-interface to get the data into the database.

Even if the user directly connected to the database, they would still need some kind of application to do that and a web interface is as good as any.